# implicit declaration using -std=c99

Tags: c, gcc

I'm getting this warning: (`-std=c99 -pedantic`)

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strndup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

but I'm importing these libs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

So what?! :(

---

```
// file.c:
    #include "file.h"
    strndup(...)
// file.h:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
```

Comment: can you show us how you call strndup ? and its called including not importing and those are C headers not libs.

Comment: @mux: How it's called seems pretty irrelevant, the issue is most likely that GCC doesn't provide this function declaration using the specified flags (or not at all in the case of MinGW).

Comment: Does your program link despite the warning?  As 2 of the comments above say, strndup is not in MinGW in either the headers or the libs

Comment: @NiklasB. yes you're right, I thought the context could be relevant, sorry.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue is your usage of the `-std=c99` option. Since `strndup()` *isn't* part of C99, and you're asking the compiler to go into standards compliant mode, it won't provide the prototype for it. It still links of course, because your C library has it.

While you may be able to coax `gcc` into providing it by specifying feature macros yourself, I'd say it doesn't make much sense to be in C99 compliance mode *and* ask for GNU extensions for example. `gcc` already provides a mode for this, which will solve your warning: `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: gnu99 is not the solution. Defining the right *feature test macros* is the solution. To use the interfaces defined in POSIX, you must define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to the desired version (200809L) before including any headers (or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` if you also want the full XSI option).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `strndup()` isn't POSIX either. According to the man page it's a GNU extension. Rather than using a feature test macro to enable it, why wouldn't you just use `gnu99` mode?

Comment: The Austin Group begs to differ: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html

Comment: And as for why to do it the correct way, the answer is that it's portable. Defining the right feature test macro will make your program work on any POSIX conformant system. Using "gnu99" will make your program work on Linux+glibc. Actually the purpose of `-std=gnu99` is mainly to enable GNU C *compiler* extensions, which work anywhere GCC is available, but the GNU libc specific *library* extensions will not be universally available.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. Your argument for portability makes sense. What I was mainly getting at was that if you were going to use a GNU extension function, may as well just enable GNU extensions in general -- but, seems my man page could use updating. I'd agree then that this (i.e. what you said) is probably a better solution then, if we just want access to that function.

Answer (score 9):

My `man strndup` says

```
Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       strdup():
           _SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
           _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
           || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
       strndup():
           Since glibc 2.10:
               _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700
           Before glibc 2.10:
               _GNU_SOURCE
       strdupa(), strndupa(): _GNU_SOURCE
```

So I'd need to, eg, `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` **before** the first `#include` in your file.
see `man 7 feature_test_macros`

Answer (score 8):

`strndup` is a GNU extension, so you need to compile with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` on the command line, or stick a `#define _GNU_SOURCE 1` in your source files before the `#include` lines

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, and I added `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` and the warning went away.